# How to resolve Test-Connection error: "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter" name 'TargetName'."

Tags: powershell

I tried `Test-Connection -TargetName www.google.com`, which is [what most examples show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7.1#examples). And I got the error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter" name 'TargetName'."

I didn't find many results when googling that error.

I'm on Powershell Version 5.1, which I know by running `$PSVersionTable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My go-to method for discovering parameter names is `Get-Command -Syntax` - which in this case shows us the correct name in 5.1 is `ComputerName`:

```
PS ~> Get-Command Test-Connection -Syntax

Test-Connection [-ComputerName] <string[]> [-AsJob] [-DcomAuthentication <AuthenticationLevel>] [-WsmanAuthentication <string>] [-Protocol <string>] [-BufferSize <int>] [-Count <int>] [-Impersonation <ImpersonationLevel>] [-ThrottleLimit <int>] [-TimeToLive <int>] [-Delay <int>] [<CommonParameters>]

Test-Connection [-ComputerName] <string[]> [-Source] <string[]> [-AsJob] [-DcomAuthentication <AuthenticationLevel>] [-WsmanAuthentication <string>] [-Protocol <string>] [-BufferSize <int>] [-Count <int>] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-Impersonation <ImpersonationLevel>] [-ThrottleLimit <int>] [-TimeToLive <int>] [-Delay <int>] [<CommonParameters>]

Test-Connection [-ComputerName] <string[]> [-DcomAuthentication <AuthenticationLevel>] [-WsmanAuthentication <string>] [-Protocol <string>] [-BufferSize <int>] [-Count <int>] [-Impersonation <ImpersonationLevel>] [-TimeToLive <int>] [-Delay <int>] [-Quiet] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Answer (score 1):

What helped me find the solution was just entering `Test-Connection` and seeing what parameter it would prompt me for. It prompted me for `ComputerName`. So then I tried running `Test-Connection -ComputerName www.google.com` and it worked!

Comment: The documentation pages have a dropdown on the top left where you can pick the _version_ required - if you pick `5.1` you'll find the examples all use `-ComputerName` :-)